# Example text next to TextInput box

Tags: gosu, guidewire

Is there anyway to put some example text next to a text box field.

[image]

In the picture above I have Loan Number. Next to the text box I want to have some text that says "Please enter a loan number". Is this possible in guidwire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Text Input should have helpText property where you can enter your tolltip text.

[image]

Not sure what GW version you are on, but if you don't have this option let me know as there is another way to do this.

Comment: Beat me to it!!

Comment: I have help text but it only shows that when you hover over the field. I want the text to always be visible to the user

Comment: In that case you can just add a label next to it with your text.

Comment: Tried that but it won't let me add a label next to it. I click and drag the label over but it will only let me put it above or below.

Comment: You could do a text field above, or a new input column on the right, but it's going to be a beast to get it to line up properly, and as soon as they resize their browser window you're hosed.

Comment: So there is no way in guidewire to have text on the right side of a input? That stinks! thanks guys